# Collaborative Merge Conflict Resolution in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

Imagine the following scenario: when trying to merge the changes on the trunk with a branch, there are conflicts on 10 different files which are authored and maintained by 3 different developers. This means that a single team member cannot conduct the conflict resolution, as there are parts in which he is not competent enough.

Is there a way to carry out the conflict resolution collaboratively? In other words, can this work be divided among several team members who can commit their resolutions separately?

Answer (score 1):

Just as idea: it can be **3 sequential merges** (from branch to trunk), performed by 3 developers

Main idea behind the scene - each developer touch only "own" files, all other conflicted files before commit are prepared with `svn resolve --accept 'mine-conflict'` (maybe 'mine-full', because "my" is in this case are files of trunk)

Can't recall, how to to it fully in TSVN GUI (and is it possible at all), try to find answer in GUI (or use CLI-mode)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't seem to find something similar in Tortoise SVN. Also, I don't get this part: if one of the developers resolves "own" files and "prepares" other conflicting files, how will others see the files on which they should work on (if I get it right, there will be no conflicts after the first developer's commit)?

Comment: @Narek - conficts on sequential merges after 1-st merge still exist: each merge leave "foreign" trunk-files untouched. Have I to write simplified scheme?

Comment: Are there any decent resources in web describing the process of sequential merge with Tortoise SVN?

Comment: @Narek - I suppose "no", because sequential merges in fact are the same as *just merge*